# TexLive's texmf-local folder storing a lot of files (over 80GB!)

Tags: texlive, texmf, memory, texmf-local

Using a storage scanning application I noticed that on my macOS Sierra a lot of files are being stored in the folder /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local. It seems that in this texmf-local some kind of old backup of the full system is being stored: it includes all folders of my mac, such as Downloads, Dropbox, Music etc, which are not compatible with the current folders... See below:

[image]

Does anyone know what is the importance of the texmf-local folder? And if/how I could prevent Texlive to do something similar in the future? (and why it stored everything in the first place?)

Btw, I use MacTex-2015.

Comment: You should first figure out why a backup of your Music etc got into the texmf-local folder. It's not TeXLive that does this. Did you set up any auto-backup software, say Time Machine or whatever it's called, and tell it to save backups there?

Comment: Something very weird has gone on: I wonder if you've managed to create some link you shouldn't have

Comment: @ShreevatsaR No idea. I probably did use Time Machine in the past but the texmf folder is the most hidden folder ever so it's quite unlikely that I did that... Is it anyway safe to delete everything in texmf-local?

Comment: I'm not sure whether it's safe to delete *everything*, but *as far as TeX is concerned* it's probably safe to delete the biggest directories in your screenshot: it shows that together they account for over (37.8 + 11.1 + 11.0 + 7.1 + 5.7 + 4.9 + 4.2 =) 81.8 GB of the 81.9 GB. (I think it might actually be safe to delete most of it; on my computer the `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local` directory consists of a structure of empty directories and a single `ls-R` file. But I'm not sure of the full details of what it's used for.) Also, delete safely: check for links, and try moving first.

Comment: This are your files (your dropbox, your pictures), so you will have to decide if you want to keep them. Nobody here can know why they are there and if they are important.

Comment: It's also suspicious that your `/Users` directory is only 58.9 GB, which is significantly less than the sum of your Downloads, Music, Desktop, Dropbox, etc. So as @UlrikeFischer says you may want to tread very carefully when deleting them; all that we can say here is that unless you want to typeset it, TeX doesn't care about your Music.

Comment: First find out if these are symbolic links of really folders/files; run `ls -alF /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local` which should give your that information. Then figure out how this happened so it doesn't happen again. Then figure out why you don't have the proper folder structure that was set up by the MacTeX installer on initial setup. Then make sure those folders already exist in their proper locations.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I can only ask. If somebody here (with knowledge about texmf folders, which I don't have) ever heard of a similar problem, he/she could know maybe why this happened.

Comment: Asking how this could happen is one thing, asking if it is safe to *delete* the files is another.

Comment: by all sake don't delete those files before making sure you have them in their proper place in your HOME folder! it is very strange that `/Users` is only 58.9GB.

Comment: @jfbu In the texmf folder there is an old backup/copy, not compatible with my current files in the home folder. So reason that /Users is much smaller is because the actual Download folder is empty now for example

Comment: if these are really old backups and you have the real current things in your `~/Downloads`, `~/Music` etc... then it does look like you can remove them from texmf-local because they don't belong there. `texmf-local` is a priori quasi empty and it is for your additions to TeXLive files.

Comment: I faintly remember that on upgrades between two MacOS versions something strange could happen. Best is to ask on the mactex mailing list.